# Can't enable termination protection on a running ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working with a few ec2 instances through the AWS console and I can't seem to enable Termination Protection.

When I right click on one of my instances and select "Change Termination Protection" and click "Yes, Enable", I get the error:

```
An error occurred while changing the termination protection setting of this instance.
```

This seems to happen on my Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows Server 2012 instances. I have used termination protection in the past so I'm not sure what has changed.

Thanks!

Comment: I have nevered seen this myself. I will recommend you log a call with Amazon. In the meantime, can you create another Win2012 instance using the **Free tier eligible** and see if this issue occurs.

Comment: seems like you would have better luck at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Figured it out.

Apparently you **cannot enable Termination Protection with Spot Instances**, at least using the current AWS console. I have no definitive proof on this but

1. Enabling termination protection on my spot instances does not work but enabling termination protection on all my other instances does work.
2. When you check "Request Spot Instances" in the current AWS Console on page three of the Launch Instance Wizard, the checkbox lower on the page labeled "Enable termination protection" disappears.

Something to muddy the waters however is [this section](http://pages.citebite.com/g2b4h0o9u0ept) from some AWS documentation which suggests that Termination Protection on Spot Instances is possible. Granted, it's an aside on a page in the MapReduce docs and the real Termination Protection page makes no similar mention, but it's there nonetheless.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The termination protection reference you found is about termination protection of an EMR cluster, not an instance; the reference makes the point that clusters have a termination protection option, and clusters can include spot instances, and termination protection of the cluster doesn't keep to spot instances alive. +1 for finding your own solution.